Style CSS file parent query possible?
I wanted to understand if this is possible or not, and is there any other way to do something like below?
In css file we can add query for different screen resolutions, So all css will apply to specific screen only.
@media (max-width: 768px){

}

Is there any way to add common parent class? Like below
@media (class: .home-page){

  h1{

  }

  .banner-title{

  }

}

So that '.home-page' class will auto apply to all css we are adding in this code block.
and CSS will only apply if there is parent class named '.home-page' is in HTML dom
I tried to search, but It might not be possible as of now.

Using CSS nesting

You can write
.home-page h1 {
  ...
}

.home-page  .banner-title{
  ...
}

In this case you have to write the parent class every time.
But if you use a CSS framework like for example SASS, LESS etc. you can write
.home-page {
  h1 {
    ...
  }

  .banner-title{
    ...
  }
}

See for example here: https://lesscss.org/
